# Weblogic xss vulnerablity : html character entities getting decoded in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, weblogic, xss

I am **using a filter to prevent xss by encoding html character** of my jsp form parameters.

I am resolving them in jsp using ${param} expression.

**This is working fine in tomcat as the values are resolved as is, but on weblogic the values are getting decoded, causing the XSS to succeed**

I am using this simple code in jsp to test it

```
<c:set var="testing" value="eb011&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=a onerror=confirm(1)&gt;47379"/>
<input type="hidden" name="encoding" value="${testing }"/>
```

Result in tomcat

```
<input type="hidden" onerror="confirm(1)&gt;47379&quot;/" src="a" &gt;&lt;img="" value="eb011" name="encoding">
```

Result in weblogic

```
<input type="hidden" value="eb011" name="encoding"><img onerror="confirm(1)" src="a">47379"/&gt;
```

**Please tell me why is weblogic decoding html codes and what could be done to prevent it.**

Answer (score 1):

I have never used weblogic in my life, but I do little know about XSS. After some doing some google I found following  method to encode the the html entities in weblogic. I guess that will help you out.

> WebLogic Server provides the weblogic.servlet.security.Utils.encodeXSS() method to replace the  special characters in user-supplied data. To use this method, provide the user-supplied data as input.  For example 
>   `<%= weblogic.servlet.security.Utils.encodeXSS(
>   javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getParameter("userInput"))%>`

From:[Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/reference.html)

> WebLogic Server provides the weblogic.servlet.security.Utils.encodeXSS() method to replace the special characters in user-supplied data.
>  `out.print(defaultGreeting + " " + 
>   weblogic.security.servlet.encodeXSS(name) + "!");`

From: [Using a WebLogic Server Utility Method](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WBAPP/progservlet.htm#WBAPP262)